# console-kit-daemon - can it be stopped?

Tags: ubuntu, daemon

I have 60 instances of Console Kit daemon on Ubuntu 9.04 server installation. Is it safe to kill those or stop these processes. They seem to be taking about 20% of RAM each(see on htop).

Comment: 60 * 20% = 1200%

Comment: :) It's just so many threads. The process as a whole takes 20%. I confirmed with the command given below by Gilles.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

ConsoleKit manages console logins in graphical mode (i.e. with `gdm` or equivalent); if your server doesn't have those, you don't need it, but then it won't be started anyway. Also, you may be interested in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/66765/disable-usage-of-console-kit-daemon-in-ubuntu).

But you don't really have 60 instances taking 20% of RAM each. The ConsoleKit daemon is multithreaded, and htop shows a separate line for each thread. It's really one process and there's a single copy of that memory; you can confirm that with
`ps wwu -C console-kit-daemon`.

Additionally, the memory usage shown by htop includes code memory, some of which is likely to be shared with other processes using the same dynamic libraries.

Comment: We only have to login remotely, so we can disable them right ? Is there a clean way of shutting down X and console-kit. Thanks ?

Comment: To disable graphical mode console logins, you can remove `/etc/X11/default-display-manager`. Stop the running instance with `stop gdm`.

Answer (score 22):

On a debian based headless server the way to remove and stop console kit that I found is this

`apt-get remove dbus-x11 consolekit`

`apt-get autoremove`

Tested on debian testing (jessie)

Comment: I had no `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` file, and I figure you might as well uninstall the package if you don't need it. I prefer this solution

Answer (score 4):

All Ubuntu machines (all versions) I know has those appearing in htop (mine has, servers have) and the number shown is 0,2 which means 0.2% and not 20% (htop reports are already in %). Anyways as Gilles said before they are not effectively running.
mysqld do the same thing on mysql servers (not 60 but a lot) each reporting they are eating a good part of RAM (like 20 or 30% each) and that is not possible. You can check the free memory and you'll see they are not using this RAM.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but shut down X before killing them.

Comment: how do you shutdown X, I don't find it running under ps -ef | grep X or grep gdm or xdm

Comment: `sudo killall Xorg`

Answer (score -3):

You can test it disabling the console-kit-daemon executable with:

```
chmod 000 /usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon
killall console-kit-daemon
```

and test if your system is healthier. Mine gave no problem after that,
but I hadn't gdm processes running.